# How to set OpenCL device to Intel, via environment variables

Tags: opencv, gpu, opencl, intel

I am running an opencl code that automatically use nvidia as it's device.

How can I changed that via environment variable?

Can I use OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE? If so, what should be it's value?

Answer (score 1):

This is the format:

<'Platform'>:<'CPU|GPU|ACCELERATOR|nothing=GPU/CPU'>:<'DeviceName or ID'>

as described here: [OpenCL Module Introduction](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html)

In my case, I should use: 
:GPU:0, or :GPU:1

But, the id's are not deterministic, so I use Context to find the right Id:

Context context;
    context.create(Device::TYPE_GPU);

```
for (int i = 0; i < context.ndevices(); ++i)
{
    Device device = context.device(i);

    if (device.name().find("Intel") != string::npos)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```